# Benefits of having CodedUI test, over Automated Test Cases (via Action Recording)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

The sole purpose of Coded UI is to perform Automated functional testing, that doesn't need human interactions. We can have a list of TestCases managed in TFS and we can record User Action while running a Test Case using MTM (Microsoft Test Manager). These automated recorded actions can also be repeated any number of time after we find a change in build.

I have referred a couple of articles suggesting Generating a Coded UI TestMethod , from Recorded action of the Testcase or linking (Associate Automation) them to the TestCase. for example:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286652.aspx

I am NOT able to understand the advantage of having both an automated Coded UI Test and recorded actions of the same TestCase? I must be missing an objective, which is must for me to know before I move further.

I know we can add number of asserts further after having it converted to Coded UI testmethod. But is this the only advantage of having Coded UI over , Action recording?

Any suggestions?

Regards
Sumeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tests executed by MTM have manual verification checks of what is displayed on the screen. There will be test steps with words such as "*Expect to see ...*" or "*The value ... should be shown ...*". To execute the test properly with MTM each of these verification steps should be performed. There is no way with MTM to automate these checks.

Converting to a Coded UI test does not directly add the checks, but Coded UI allows automated checks to be added into the test. Having converted an MTM test to a Coded UI test, the cross-hairs tool of Coded UI (also called the assertion tool and similar terms) can be used to add assertions that values on the screen contain the expected values.

An additional reason for converting is that the full programming facilities of C# or VB can be used to add extra features into the test.